# How to loop back to the start if I enter aaa?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

just started learning c++ a few days ago. How do I make my code back to the start after typing in aaa for the first input. It just starts to exit the program instead where I would like it to ask error enter an number if the user inputs aaa or just any character or letter.

I want to program to run exactly like this where when I enter a when asked "Enter the number of numbers you want to check" and I input a it doesn't end the program but goes back to the start and ask the same question. I want it to check both conditions of it not being a negative number and no letters. Have to use cin.fail

http://cpp.sh/9tqrx

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int numberCheck=-1;
    while(numberCheck<0){
        cout<<"Enter the number of numbers you want to check: ";
        cin>>numberCheck;
        
         
      {
         
          cin.clear();
          
          cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      }
        if(numberCheck<0)
            cout<<"Wrong number. Try one more time" << endl;
  
      

    }
    
  
    
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<numberCheck;j++){
        //description variable:
        int number=-1;

        //input number:
        while((number<1)||(number>1000)){
            cout<<"Input a number between 1 and 1000: ";
            cin>>number;
    
      {
         
          
          cin.clear();
          
          cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      }
            if((number<1)||(number>1000))
                cout<<"That number is not valid or character.  Input a number." <<endl;
         
        }

        //Determine if a number is a prime number or not.
        //A prime number is one whose only exact divisors are 1
        //and the number itself (such as 2, 3, 5, 7, etc.).
        int i;
        int nDiv=0;
        int isSimple=1;
        for(i=2;i<number;i++)
            if(number%i==0)
            {
                if(isSimple==1){
                    cout<<"That is not a prime number.  Divisors are:"<<endl;
                    cout<<"1\t";
                    nDiv=1;
                    isSimple=0;
                   }
                cout<<i<<"\t";
                nDiv++;
                if(nDiv%10==0)
                    cout<<endl;
            }
        if(isSimple==0) //if not simple, output last item:
           cout<<number<<endl;
        else
           cout<<"That is a prime number."<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the input as a string. Check if the string matches your definition of a number (whatever that is). If it does then convert the string to a number. If it doesn't then ask for the input again. Frankly I think this is a bit difficult for a beginner (though don't let me stop you if you really want to try).

Comment: like @john said, receiving your input as string will give you flexibility ,check some conditions and perform some actions. Also check out "parsing string as an integer" to see how to handle your input.

Comment: Get rid of that `cin.clear(); cin.ignore(...);` stuff. That's cargo cult programming.